# Comparing String Value

Tags: php, algorithm, sha

I am trying to build hash of SHA256 from the string using `hash_hmac`

```
$key = chr(hexdec('17'));
// value of key is blank 
$test = chr(hexdec('17')) == '' ? true : false
// value of test is false
```

so I want to know what is the value of `$key` how can I compare this

```
$signature1 = hash_hmac('SHA256', "st=1453362060~exp=1453363260~acl=/*", chr(hexdec('17')));
$signature2 = hash_hmac('SHA256', "st=1453362060~exp=1453363260~acl=/*", "");

// signature1 == 020cb911b6415b14f6b1f955adf55be3b17bcbd77a3987408cb41406e39bfc82
// signature2 == 9356975e2119102a773dbd45e4f06d124246794a451c4aee320888bd3f857377
```

why is it generating different key ?

Answer (score 0):

The value of `$key` is not directly printable but has a length different to an empty string so you are not supplying the same parameters to the `hash_hmac` function on both occasions. Perhaps the `$test` variable needs to be used?

```
if( !defined( 'BR' ) ) define('BR','<br />' );

$key = chr(hexdec('17'));
$test = chr(hexdec('17')) == '' ? true : false; 


$signature1 = hash_hmac('SHA256', "st=1453362060~exp=1453363260~acl=/*", $test );
$signature2 = hash_hmac('SHA256', "st=1453362060~exp=1453363260~acl=/*", '' );

echo 'key:'.$key.' length:'.strlen($key).' length:'.strlen('').BR;
echo $signature1.BR.$signature2;
```

### output

```
key: length:1 length:0
728079ac9885314df2cc1207e8eb79ada329d7d4172ce6574a561c540f039c02
728079ac9885314df2cc1207e8eb79ada329d7d4172ce6574a561c540f039c02
```